# Limit max bandwidth per IP

Tags: linux, linux-networking, rate-limiting

I have some partners, that uses one of my linux servers as a gateway. The problem is I need to limit bandwidth per client ip address on this gateway. My partners client ip ranges are not known to me. 
I have been looking at Traffic Control and iptables but failed find a solution.

Comment: While `tc` is not entirely easy to understand and use, it's a way to set the kernel up to give certain flows parts of given bandwith. I was going to write up something but only started with an example... https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/Traffic_control, see also http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-htb, http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm and http://www.lartc.org/.

Answer (score -1):

The netem kernel module, controlled by iproute.

You need to compile Netem with the kernel:

Networking -->
   Networking Options -->
     QoS and/or fair queuing -->
        Network emulator
Once the netem module loaded, iproute's tc allows you things like:

tc qdisc add dev  tap0 root netem delay 50ms loss 50%
(50 % packet loss, extra delay of 50 ms)